# How can I find the distance between consecutive coordinates in R?

Tags: r, coordinates, distance

I have a dataframe similar in structure to the one created below:

```
id <- rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), each = 3)
date <- seq(as.Date("2019-01-30"), as.Date("2019-02-10"), by="days")
lon <- c(-87.1234, -86.54980, -86.234059, -87.2568, -87.65468, -86.54980, -86.234059, -86.16486, -87.156546, -86.234059, -86.16486, -87.156546)
lat <- c(26.458, 26.156, 25.468, 25.157, 24.154, 24.689, 25.575, 25.468, 25.157, 24.154, 26.789, 26.456)
data <- data.frame(id, date, lon, lat)
data <- data %>% arrange(id, date)
```

I would like to measure the distance between *consecutive* points grouped by id. I do not want a distance matrix, which is why I refrain from using raster::pointDistance. I tried separating each unique id into its own sf dataframe (in reality I have ~400 ids so I kind of have to separate for the actual calculation due to the size) and using the following code:

```
#put rows for each id in their own dataframes
un1 <- unique(data$id)
for(i in seq_along(un1)) 
  assign(paste0('id', i), subset(data, id == un1[i]))
#create point distance function
pt.dist <- function(dat){dat$pt.dist <- st_distance(dat, by_element=TRUE)
  return(dat)}
#run function across every dataframe in working environment
e <- .GlobalEnv
nms <- ls(pattern = "id", envir = e)
for(nm in nms) e[[nm]] <- pt.dist(e[[nm]])
```

When I run this, all I get is a geometry column with lon and lat listed in a pair. I have also tried segclust2d::calc_distance like below:

```
distance <- function(dat){calc_dist(dat, coord.names = c("lon", "lat"), smoothed = FALSE)}
for(nm in nms) e[[nm]] <- distance(e[[nm]])
```

which returns a column where the distances are all 0 meters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are calculating a geographical distance, why did you include the [tag:euclidean-distance] tag? The two are completely different.

Comment: Apologies, it was not purposeful. Thank you for the response.

Comment: No worries, I know (as well) that the tag-recommendation is imperfect. Most of the rationale for my comment was to ensure I did not misunderstand your intent (also answered by you accepting my answer). Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geosphere::dist*` support this. The most-accurate is `distVincentyEllipsoid` (though it may be slower with larger data), followed by `distVincentySphere` and `distHaversine`. Its return value is in meters.

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(dist = c(NA, geosphere::distVincentyEllipsoid(cbind(lon, lat)))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 12 x 5
#    id    date         lon   lat    dist
#    <chr> <date>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1 a     2019-01-30 -87.1  26.5     NA 
#  2 a     2019-01-31 -86.5  26.2  66334.
#  3 a     2019-02-01 -86.2  25.5  82534.
#  4 b     2019-02-02 -87.3  25.2     NA 
#  5 b     2019-02-03 -87.7  24.2 118175.
#  6 b     2019-02-04 -86.5  24.7 126758.
#  7 c     2019-02-05 -86.2  25.6     NA 
#  8 c     2019-02-06 -86.2  25.5  13744.
#  9 c     2019-02-07 -87.2  25.2 105632.
# 10 d     2019-02-08 -86.2  24.2     NA 
# 11 d     2019-02-09 -86.2  26.8 291988.
# 12 d     2019-02-10 -87.2  26.5 105423.
```

### base R

We can get to the same thing with `ave`. Because it only iterates over a single column, we pass row-indices as the first argument to be grouped. Because it coerces the return values to be the same `class` as the first argument, we convert the row-indices to `numeric`.

```r
data$dist2 <- ave(
  as.numeric(seq_len(nrow(data))),  # values to use in calc
  data$id,                          # grouping variable(s)
  FUN = function(i) c(NA, geosphere::distVincentyEllipsoid(data[i, c("lon", "lat")]))
)
data
#    id       date       lon    lat     dist2
# 1   a 2019-01-30 -87.12340 26.458        NA
# 2   a 2019-01-31 -86.54980 26.156  66334.13
# 3   a 2019-02-01 -86.23406 25.468  82534.47
# 4   b 2019-02-02 -87.25680 25.157        NA
# 5   b 2019-02-03 -87.65468 24.154 118175.40
# 6   b 2019-02-04 -86.54980 24.689 126757.93
# 7   c 2019-02-05 -86.23406 25.575        NA
# 8   c 2019-02-06 -86.16486 25.468  13743.74
# 9   c 2019-02-07 -87.15655 25.157 105631.82
# 10  d 2019-02-08 -86.23406 24.154        NA
# 11  d 2019-02-09 -86.16486 26.789 291988.42
# 12  d 2019-02-10 -87.15655 26.456 105422.87
```

Internally, the second call to the `FUN` function passed `i=c(4,5,6)` for the `"b"` id group. Those numbers do not need to be consecutive; in fact, one strength of `ave` over other group-processing functions is that it always returns in the same order as the input, so it is safe to reassign its value back to the original frame.